# Failure delivering result from custom activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-sqlite

I've been trying to fix this for a while now and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with what I'm doing. I tried to look up similar issues others were having but their solutions don't solve my issues it seems. Anywho...

I'm getting the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1327, result=-1, data=Intent { (has
>   extras) }} to activity
>   {thinkgeist.wheresmystuff/thinkgeist.wheresmystuff.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed
>   object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM items
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4053)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

When trying to return from the method I created called CreateActivity. Here's how it is called from 
**MainActivity:**

```
public void createItem(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_ACTIVITY);
}
```

After this calling code we would hop over to
**CreateActivity:**

```
public class CreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);

    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDescription);
    final EditText etSerial = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSerial);
    final EditText etLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLocation);
    final EditText etQuantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etQuantity);

    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = etName.getText().toString();
            String description = etDescription.getText().toString();
            String serial = etSerial.getText().toString();
            String location = etLocation.getText().toString();
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(etQuantity.getText().toString());

            Item item = new Item(1, name, description, serial, location, quantity);

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent.putExtra("name", name);
            resultIntent.putExtra("description", description);
            resultIntent.putExtra("serial", serial);
            resultIntent.putExtra("location", location);
            resultIntent.putExtra("quantity", quantity);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

Finally the code in **MainActivity** that handles the response...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Extract data from Create Activity

    if(requestCode == CREATE_ACTIVITY && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            String name = data.getStringExtra("name");
            String description = data.getStringExtra("description");
            String serial = data.getStringExtra("serial");
            String location = data.getStringExtra("location");
            int quantity = data.getIntExtra("quantity", 1);
            addItemToDatabase(name, description, serial, location, quantity);

    }
}
```

Honestly I think this just has to be me using some improper syntax somewhere as I'm not entirely familiar with android development yet. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed
>   object: SQLiteQuery

I suppose in `addItemToDatabase()` you are trying to perform an operation on database, which is closed.

Comment: Yeah, seems so, include code of addItemToDatabase() function into you question, please.